# client requesting from web server

Tags: java

I have coded a simple java client to send requests and receive data from my my java web server. The server is capable of handling persistent connections and everything works fine when I use browser to send requests however when I send requests using my client it only works with non persistent connections. when I use my java client to send requests it would receive the data requested from the server and then just freezes. My code for java client:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String sentence;
        String modifiedSentence;
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6789);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Enter the file name that you would like to request from Server:");
        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();

        System.out.println("would you like to have a persistent connection (yes/no):");
        String sentence1 = inFromUser.readLine();
        if(sentence1.equals("yes")){sentence1="Connection: keep-alive";}

        else{sentence1="Connection: close";}
        outToServer.writeBytes("GET /"+sentence + "\r\n");
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence1+"\r\n");
        outToServer.writeBytes("\r\n");

        while ((modifiedSentence=inFromServer.readLine()) != null) 
        {
              System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
        }

        System.out.println("done");

        clientSocket.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you try to `modifiedSentence=inFromServer.readLine()` after the server closed the connection (which closes the socket and the other streams as well) and you get a `java.net.SocketException`.

Try surrounding it with try/catch and print the error message / stacktrace

Comment: The server does not close the connection if it's persistent. I don't see any errors from the client side.

Comment: If I close the socket connection from server side after sending requested data then the client works fine but that defeats the whole purpose of having persistent connection. everything works fine using browser though

Comment: @zista MY bad that I missed it: before you open the connection (socket) you should decide if you want the connection to be persistent by using `socket.setKeepAlive(true)` - doing so after you already opened the connection probably causes the freeze.

Comment: should that go under client or server?

Comment: The client (since its the "side" that opens the connection)

Comment: I tried this clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6789);
        clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);  still not working

Comment: It's hard when I can't debug... last shot: when you use "writeBytes" the higher 8 bits are discarded (for each character in the string). Try to use `PrintWriter` instead, here's an example:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html